# How can I check a third-party website for updates before a Git trigger runs?

Tags: git, joomla, webhooks, continuous-deployment

I have a private repo with a joomla project in (all core files are gitignored) and I'd like that when someone of my team pulls from a specific branch, a trigger starts which checks if there is a new version of Joomla, maybe by checking in a docker repository, and then firstly it installs the image, then it pulls the files from the repo so that everyone is sure to have the last joomla version when pulling from that branch.

Would it be possible something like this? Thank you

Comment: If the core is ignored, how does updating it help anyone?

Comment: I'm thinking about two possible situations: 
1) Files are uploaded on local machine after pull
2) Core files aren't gitignored and when there's an update in the update_branch they are automatically merged in other branches.

What do you think would be the best?

Comment: @Ermanno if you and your team are doing Joomla dev work, please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and recommend that your colleagues do the same.